# How to define subsumptions in prolog lists

Tags: prolog

To do unification in Prolog, we write:

```
match(X, Y) :-
    X=Y.
```

Instead of matching (X, Y) succeeding if X = Y. I would like it to succeed if each elements of X is a subset or superset of the corresponding element of Y.

This is my code of subsumption:

```
:- op(400, yfx, <<<).

subset(X, X).
subset(X, Y) :-
    X <<< Y.
subset(X, Z) :-
    X <<< Y,
    subset(Y, Z).
```

UPDATE:

In my code, I have these facts of subsumptions:

```
man <<< human.
human <<< animal.
animal <<< living.
```

what I need is to change the match code above to work as follows:

If i have:

```
[living, X] ==> [mortal, X].
```

and

```
[man, socrates].
```

I would like to be able to prove:

```
?- mortal(socrates). 
yes.
```

there is a match between man and living as man here is subset by living.

Comment: Are these simple lists, or compounds (list within list) lists? And if the latter, what constitutes a subset? In other words, would `A` be considered a subset of `B` if you flatten both of them and `A flattened` is a subset of `B flattened`?

Comment: Your question can mean a lot of things. Seems you want to define your own language, but you leave out most of it. E.g. what is the difference between `<<<` and `==>`.  They seem to serve a similar purpose.

Comment: In my example, I mean by ( <<< ) is subset, for example: man <<< human. And I mean by ( ==> ) implies. A ==> B.

Answer (score 2):

there is an ISO predicate [subsumes_term](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subsumes_term/2) that performs that check.
Try

```
1 ?- subsumes_term(X,1).
true.

2 ?- subsumes_term(1,X).
false.
```

To apply to all lists elements, use maplist/3

```
maplist(subsumes_term, L1, L2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subset([],[]).
subset([H|T],[X|Y]) :- (sublist(H,X); sublist(X,H)), subset(T,Y).

| ?- subset([[1,2],[3,4]],[[1],[3]]).

true ? ;

| ?- subset([[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2,3],[3]]).

true ? ;
```

You can define sublist as:

```
pe([],[]).
pe([H|T],T).
sublist([H|T],[H]).
sublist([H|T],[H|X]) :- sublist(T,X).
sublist([H|T],[X|Y]) :- X \= H, pe([H|T],L), sublist(L,[X|Y]).
```

Comment: How can we define sublist here?

Comment: `sublist` is an inbuilt predicate.

Comment: This is what I have got:
! Existence error in user:sublist/2
! procedure user:sublist/2 does not exist
! goal:  user:sublist([1,2],[1])

Comment: Added how to define sublist

Comment: A slightly simpler sublist: `sublist([], []).
sublist([X|T], [X|L]) :-
    sublist(T, L).
sublist(S, [_|L]) :-
    sublist(S, L).` GNU Prolog has a `sublist/2` built in, but SWI Prolog does not.

Comment: Thank you, the problem has not been solved. I would like to talk to somebody in Skype (bremax355) to explain the problem better.